# Simmilar to orbot the tor android app can we use Orxify to anonymize the Android traffic without any configuration of the ports

Tags: anonymity, orbot

Here's a [question](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/85278/how-does-the-orxify-app-do-what-not-even-the-official-tor-client-for-android-can) in which the OP asks can we use the android app called [Orxify](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.inetric.anonify&hl=en) which claims to use the Tor network and automatically configures the ports.

I know that in order to anonymize the Traffic in Android you need to use the Orbot which configures all the incoming and the outgoing ports through the Orbot.But again as the OP provides is this kind of method to anonymize the traffic really good or it's just another fake application.

As Tor is Open source does it mean that apps like the above could actually use the Tor network to anonymize the traffic.

Comment: It's a closed source, for profit app. You have no meaningful guarantees about what it is doing. I'd err on the side of caution and use Orbot. This app isn't doing anything more than Orbot and what it *is* doing, it isn't open about. Not trustworthy.

Answer (score 0):

If Orxify anonymizes the traffic on a regular device, it would also do the same on one that has its traffic torrified, just mixing it up more making it in theory safer

Also, of course open source can be useful, and helpful. If I write a random number generator doesn't matter if it's open source, if its truely random or random enough you cant manipulate it.

Comment: "just mixing it up more making it in theory safer" <- this isn't true.